# Correlation analysis among large number of variables

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, pearson-r

How can I check correlation among large number of variables? I can check the scatter plot between every pair of variables and pearson coefficient `r` if the number is less but this approach is not practically feasible if the number is larger, say 100. What method do we follow in that case?

Comment: What do you mean by "check"?

Comment: Like how can I identify if variables are correlated or not?

Comment: You calculate the correlations, and look at them. I'm not sure I understand the problem (which might be my ignorance).

Comment: Yes that is the case when you have a small set of variables. But if I have, lets say 50 variables, I need to calculate 50*49 correlations and look at each of them to identify if any pair of variables is correlated or not. Am I going wrong somewhere here?

Comment: You could run a t-test of correlation coefficients, and flag those that are significant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like an unbearably large number to correlations to simply eyeball.

Here is some R code that generates a correlation matrix of 100 variables:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(1234)
x <- round(cor(matrix(rnorm(20000), nrow=200)), 2)
tril(x)
```

This is the first <strike>quarter</strike> 7/16 of it:

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
  [1,]  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [2,]  0.11  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [3,] -0.06  0.06  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [4,]  0.11 -0.02 -0.02  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [5,] -0.20 -0.07  0.04 -0.07  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [6,]  0.13  0.04 -0.02  0.09 -0.04  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [7,]  0.10  0.03  0.12  0.03 -0.06  0.03  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [8,]  0.02  0.00  0.03 -0.02  0.06 -0.03  0.03  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
  [9,]  0.00 -0.01  0.06  0.01  0.02  0.04 -0.04 -0.26  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [10,] -0.08  0.10  0.05 -0.03  0.07  0.02  0.05 -0.06 -0.08  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [11,]  0.04 -0.04  0.00 -0.09  0.03  0.03  0.03 -0.06  0.03  0.05  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [12,]  0.01 -0.12  0.00  0.01 -0.04  0.07 -0.01  0.02 -0.06  0.01  0.20  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [13,]  0.13  0.02  0.06  0.12  0.01  0.04  0.00 -0.10 -0.03  0.05  0.03  0.09  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [14,] -0.23 -0.01  0.07  0.02  0.00 -0.12 -0.01  0.02 -0.10  0.03 -0.06 -0.11  0.05  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [15,] -0.04  0.03  0.01  0.09  0.08  0.07 -0.05  0.02  0.10 -0.01  0.01  0.02 -0.05 -0.02  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [16,]  0.02 -0.08 -0.15 -0.07 -0.12 -0.12 -0.04 -0.09 -0.01 -0.02  0.00  0.09 -0.01 -0.06 -0.08  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [17,] -0.11 -0.12  0.14  0.07  0.07 -0.07  0.11 -0.05  0.11 -0.07  0.07 -0.01 -0.05  0.06  0.12  0.00  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [18,] -0.11 -0.02  0.08 -0.08  0.04  0.00 -0.03 -0.06 -0.03 -0.08 -0.03 -0.02  0.04 -0.01 -0.12  0.05  0.04  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [19,]  0.06 -0.10 -0.06  0.02  0.09 -0.13 -0.04  0.00  0.01 -0.01 -0.08 -0.06  0.09  0.04 -0.07  0.04 -0.09 -0.05  1.00     .     .     .     .     .     .
 [20,] -0.06 -0.01  0.00 -0.11 -0.02 -0.05  0.09  0.02 -0.03  0.04  0.00 -0.07 -0.01  0.04 -0.13  0.03  0.02  0.02  0.10  1.00     .     .     .     .     .
 [21,] -0.11 -0.01  0.15  0.02  0.09 -0.02  0.02 -0.08  0.12  0.05  0.09 -0.04  0.00  0.11  0.00  0.07  0.05  0.08  0.06 -0.05  1.00     .     .     .     .
 [22,]  0.06  0.03  0.16 -0.02 -0.07 -0.10  0.05  0.01  0.05  0.16  0.03 -0.03 -0.02  0.14  0.06  0.00 -0.01  0.01 -0.07  0.00 -0.02  1.00     .     .     .
 [23,]  0.03 -0.04 -0.05 -0.03  0.03 -0.05 -0.05  0.04 -0.02 -0.04 -0.01 -0.05 -0.01  0.05  0.00  0.06  0.01  0.00  0.09  0.02  0.06 -0.14  1.00     .     .
 [24,]  0.03  0.02  0.02 -0.07 -0.07  0.00  0.04  0.05  0.04  0.19 -0.02 -0.10 -0.06  0.02  0.03 -0.13  0.02  0.03  0.02  0.08 -0.05  0.11  0.05  1.00     .
 [25,] -0.07  0.00  0.03  0.00  0.01 -0.05  0.02 -0.06  0.02  0.06  0.04 -0.07  0.06  0.06  0.05  0.04  0.01  0.09  0.08  0.04  0.08 -0.01  0.00  0.08  1.00
 [26,]  0.01 -0.01 -0.09  0.09 -0.07  0.02  0.07  0.14 -0.13 -0.04  0.03 -0.10 -0.06  0.10  0.01  0.03  0.09  0.04 -0.08 -0.03 -0.02  0.05 -0.11 -0.02 -0.02
 [27,] -0.02 -0.09  0.19  0.06 -0.11 -0.05 -0.03  0.07 -0.03 -0.03 -0.11  0.12  0.05 -0.01 -0.03 -0.10  0.04  0.03  0.06 -0.07  0.03  0.16 -0.05  0.14 -0.04
 [28,]  0.03  0.09  0.01  0.02  0.08  0.05  0.00 -0.01  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.02 -0.12 -0.13  0.08 -0.04  0.06 -0.07 -0.03  0.09 -0.07 -0.02 -0.04  0.03  0.04
 [29,] -0.06 -0.11  0.03  0.08 -0.01  0.01  0.07  0.02  0.05 -0.02 -0.01  0.12  0.13  0.00  0.16  0.03  0.08  0.07  0.07  0.04 -0.02  0.03  0.06 -0.05  0.09
 [30,] -0.04 -0.04  0.01  0.03  0.11 -0.09 -0.06  0.07  0.08 -0.03 -0.04 -0.13  0.06 -0.09 -0.02  0.09  0.06  0.10  0.07  0.00  0.14 -0.10  0.04 -0.07 -0.10
 [31,] -0.11 -0.01  0.02  0.07  0.10  0.04  0.04  0.00 -0.08 -0.04  0.03 -0.03  0.03  0.03  0.02 -0.12 -0.01  0.01 -0.03  0.06 -0.08 -0.02 -0.16  0.00  0.03
 [32,]  0.02 -0.03 -0.01  0.03 -0.04 -0.07  0.08 -0.11  0.10 -0.11 -0.03  0.05  0.06  0.03 -0.11  0.09  0.06 -0.06 -0.11 -0.02 -0.04 -0.07  0.00 -0.07 -0.04
 [33,]  0.05 -0.03  0.06  0.06 -0.01 -0.09 -0.04  0.01 -0.03  0.03 -0.04  0.02  0.06 -0.15 -0.06 -0.01 -0.03  0.07 -0.02 -0.11  0.03  0.00 -0.04  0.01  0.09
 [34,] -0.12  0.04 -0.05  0.04 -0.04  0.01  0.02  0.00 -0.07  0.10  0.12 -0.05  0.02 -0.02 -0.01 -0.07 -0.01 -0.11 -0.01  0.12  0.09 -0.12 -0.06 -0.07  0.07
 [35,] -0.06  0.10  0.11 -0.04 -0.01 -0.01  0.01  0.03  0.02  0.05  0.02  0.00 -0.06  0.11 -0.04  0.05  0.18  0.00 -0.02 -0.05  0.02  0.05  0.01  0.16 -0.04
 [36,]  0.15 -0.03  0.03 -0.09 -0.11  0.01 -0.04  0.04 -0.04 -0.03  0.01  0.02  0.01 -0.04  0.05  0.14 -0.04  0.11  0.08  0.02  0.03  0.00  0.15  0.00  0.03
 [37,] -0.01 -0.14 -0.08 -0.11  0.08 -0.01  0.04  0.05 -0.04 -0.01 -0.01 -0.03  0.01  0.06 -0.05 -0.04  0.04  0.00  0.01  0.07 -0.08 -0.10  0.12  0.03 -0.11
 [38,]  0.05  0.02 -0.02  0.01  0.06  0.17  0.01  0.08 -0.06  0.04  0.02  0.07  0.04  0.00  0.13 -0.04 -0.10 -0.02  0.03  0.09  0.06 -0.14 -0.03 -0.12 -0.05
 [39,] -0.08 -0.05  0.01 -0.06 -0.04 -0.08 -0.07 -0.09  0.17 -0.06 -0.04 -0.10 -0.05 -0.08 -0.02 -0.11 -0.01 -0.07  0.00 -0.09  0.03 -0.02  0.00 -0.02 -0.12
 [40,]  0.08  0.03  0.02 -0.02  0.06  0.05  0.06 -0.04  0.11 -0.05  0.02  0.10  0.04 -0.01 -0.01 -0.04 -0.03 -0.09 -0.13 -0.04  0.00 -0.03  0.05 -0.07 -0.12
 [41,]  0.03  0.12  0.03 -0.06 -0.06 -0.01  0.10  0.01  0.14  0.07  0.04  0.02 -0.04  0.02 -0.03  0.17  0.02 -0.07 -0.14  0.12 -0.03  0.14 -0.07  0.00 -0.02
 [42,]  0.00  0.06 -0.02 -0.18  0.08 -0.01  0.05  0.02 -0.12 -0.10 -0.11 -0.01 -0.05 -0.07  0.01 -0.04  0.11  0.12 -0.02  0.05 -0.08 -0.02  0.07 -0.03 -0.04
 [43,] -0.05 -0.01 -0.01  0.09 -0.02 -0.02 -0.04 -0.02 -0.04  0.00 -0.06 -0.08 -0.02  0.03 -0.05 -0.03  0.05  0.05  0.02  0.06 -0.08 -0.03  0.12  0.00  0.02
 [44,] -0.06 -0.05 -0.02 -0.11  0.01  0.04  0.06  0.12 -0.10 -0.08  0.02 -0.08 -0.08 -0.10  0.06 -0.09 -0.01  0.02 -0.06  0.02  0.02  0.04  0.06 -0.03 -0.03
 [45,] -0.06 -0.12 -0.01 -0.08 -0.06  0.00  0.04 -0.12 -0.03 -0.01 -0.10  0.07 -0.13 -0.07 -0.14  0.06  0.01 -0.05 -0.10  0.15 -0.11  0.06 -0.11 -0.02  0.08
 [46,] -0.03 -0.11 -0.13 -0.09 -0.16  0.05 -0.11 -0.17  0.01 -0.01  0.03  0.06 -0.10 -0.03  0.09 -0.04  0.01  0.04 -0.06  0.06  0.06  0.01 -0.02  0.04  0.01
 [47,]  0.06 -0.01  0.07 -0.01  0.05  0.15  0.07  0.00  0.06 -0.04  0.00  0.08  0.06  0.11  0.16 -0.02  0.03  0.02 -0.10 -0.07 -0.05  0.09  0.05 -0.07 -0.12
 [48,]  0.15 -0.07 -0.08  0.09 -0.07 -0.01  0.00 -0.03 -0.02 -0.01  0.04 -0.05 -0.12  0.00  0.06  0.00 -0.07 -0.02  0.07 -0.02 -0.14 -0.03  0.15 -0.08 -0.10
 [49,] -0.02 -0.13 -0.02 -0.01  0.00 -0.09  0.00  0.09  0.07 -0.13 -0.11  0.10 -0.03  0.16  0.01  0.02  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07 -0.02 -0.03  0.08 -0.05 -0.02
 [50,] -0.01  0.01  0.06 -0.05  0.03  0.04 -0.07 -0.07  0.20 -0.08  0.01 -0.07 -0.02 -0.07  0.07 -0.04  0.03 -0.11  0.04  0.08  0.04 -0.06 -0.05  0.06  0.04
 [51,]  0.02  0.02 -0.04 -0.05 -0.05  0.05 -0.04  0.06 -0.04  0.02  0.02  0.05  0.06  0.02  0.03  0.09 -0.03  0.04 -0.07  0.03 -0.09  0.02 -0.04 -0.06  0.00
 [52,]  0.13 -0.10 -0.09  0.02 -0.07  0.01 -0.07 -0.02 -0.02 -0.03  0.04  0.14 -0.01  0.03  0.18  0.15 -0.06 -0.08  0.05 -0.15  0.02  0.05  0.00  0.01  0.00
 [53,]  0.18  0.11 -0.04  0.00 -0.07 -0.02  0.05  0.15 -0.03  0.02 -0.01  0.05  0.03  0.02 -0.15  0.09 -0.20  0.07 -0.02 -0.08  0.09  0.00 -0.02  0.05  0.02
 [54,] -0.08 -0.10  0.00 -0.02 -0.05 -0.03  0.14  0.09  0.00  0.04 -0.08  0.10 -0.06  0.12 -0.09  0.01  0.07  0.12  0.04  0.02  0.01  0.00 -0.02  0.15  0.03
 [55,] -0.04 -0.10  0.03 -0.02  0.00 -0.01 -0.17  0.02  0.02 -0.01  0.02  0.04 -0.02 -0.12 -0.01  0.04 -0.01 -0.03  0.09 -0.08 -0.03 -0.07 -0.09  0.00 -0.06
 [56,]  0.01 -0.08  0.00  0.01  0.00 -0.01  0.00  0.03 -0.05  0.18 -0.01 -0.16 -0.04 -0.05  0.02 -0.01 -0.08 -0.20 -0.04  0.04 -0.13  0.03 -0.03  0.03 -0.04
 [57,]  0.07  0.03  0.10 -0.03  0.04 -0.01  0.15  0.03  0.02  0.00  0.09 -0.02  0.11  0.01  0.00 -0.06 -0.07 -0.08  0.00  0.04 -0.03  0.00  0.11 -0.05  0.06
 [58,]  0.01  0.00 -0.09  0.07  0.09 -0.08 -0.09  0.04  0.07  0.00 -0.05 -0.02 -0.03  0.01  0.04  0.03 -0.10 -0.16  0.16  0.01 -0.15 -0.09 -0.12 -0.04 -0.07
 [59,]  0.01 -0.01 -0.02  0.00  0.06 -0.06 -0.05  0.04  0.07  0.02 -0.07  0.11  0.14 -0.04  0.01 -0.06  0.00 -0.02  0.09  0.09  0.05 -0.10  0.02 -0.09 -0.03
 [60,]  0.07 -0.01 -0.02 -0.13  0.05 -0.02 -0.06  0.02  0.09  0.07 -0.07 -0.10 -0.04 -0.03  0.04 -0.01  0.03 -0.02 -0.03 -0.05  0.05 -0.08  0.05  0.04  0.11
 [61,] -0.09  0.05  0.01 -0.12 -0.05 -0.05  0.05 -0.04  0.01  0.08 -0.01  0.00 -0.06  0.08 -0.04  0.04  0.06  0.04  0.10  0.20 -0.02  0.06 -0.07  0.00  0.06
 [62,] -0.01 -0.01 -0.08  0.01  0.10 -0.04  0.01  0.10  0.03  0.07  0.06 -0.01  0.13 -0.02 -0.05  0.05  0.11  0.08 -0.05  0.08  0.06  0.03 -0.05  0.02 -0.08
 [63,] -0.06 -0.01 -0.06 -0.07  0.06  0.04 -0.11 -0.12  0.14  0.08  0.13  0.05  0.01  0.01  0.09  0.06  0.14  0.01 -0.02 -0.01  0.11  0.02 -0.12 -0.06 -0.01
 [64,]  0.00  0.08 -0.08  0.01 -0.07 -0.05 -0.08  0.03 -0.12 -0.10  0.01  0.05  0.07  0.07 -0.04  0.05 -0.08  0.12 -0.14  0.02 -0.08  0.03  0.07 -0.17  0.09
 [65,] -0.06 -0.06 -0.04 -0.06 -0.04  0.01 -0.07  0.00 -0.07 -0.05  0.03  0.00  0.00  0.08 -0.11  0.02  0.08 -0.07  0.03  0.00 -0.05 -0.16  0.07 -0.06  0.02
 [66,] -0.10  0.06 -0.03  0.02  0.09 -0.15 -0.13  0.02 -0.05 -0.05 -0.07 -0.02  0.06 -0.08 -0.06  0.05 -0.01  0.07  0.09  0.11  0.04 -0.08  0.03 -0.01  0.14
 [67,]  0.06  0.08 -0.04  0.01 -0.15 -0.06  0.01 -0.03  0.01  0.19  0.07  0.08  0.02 -0.06  0.00  0.06  0.05 -0.01  0.09 -0.10 -0.07  0.03  0.04  0.03 -0.01
 [68,]  0.09  0.02  0.08 -0.12 -0.08  0.00  0.01 -0.12  0.00  0.04  0.04  0.02  0.08  0.04 -0.02 -0.03 -0.03 -0.09 -0.06  0.07 -0.02 -0.03 -0.05  0.01  0.05
 [69,] -0.03  0.00 -0.01  0.04  0.09  0.08 -0.05  0.07  0.01  0.03 -0.01  0.10  0.06  0.18  0.01 -0.03  0.04  0.00  0.01 -0.10  0.07 -0.10  0.07 -0.12  0.06
 [70,] -0.09 -0.07  0.11 -0.17  0.04 -0.08  0.03 -0.05  0.05 -0.03  0.00 -0.01  0.07  0.20 -0.09  0.03  0.06  0.05  0.05  0.20  0.11  0.00  0.05  0.03  0.07
 [71,]  0.02  0.00 -0.01  0.10 -0.07 -0.01  0.02  0.00  0.03 -0.15  0.00 -0.02 -0.01  0.00  0.03  0.05  0.04 -0.09  0.01  0.08 -0.11  0.02 -0.08 -0.05  0.01
 [72,] -0.01 -0.06 -0.10  0.08  0.03 -0.03 -0.10 -0.05  0.05 -0.04 -0.01  0.07 -0.07 -0.10  0.05 -0.02 -0.16  0.12  0.07  0.03 -0.12  0.07 -0.09  0.06 -0.01
 [73,]  0.05  0.12  0.08  0.01  0.11 -0.05  0.08  0.01 -0.03  0.07  0.00 -0.02  0.13 -0.14 -0.01  0.03  0.03  0.03  0.08  0.00 -0.02  0.09 -0.03  0.04 -0.06
 [74,] -0.02  0.01  0.03  0.06  0.07 -0.10  0.02 -0.02 -0.01 -0.01  0.06 -0.12 -0.06  0.07 -0.13  0.01 -0.02  0.03  0.00 -0.05  0.04  0.10 -0.11 -0.12  0.03
 [75,] -0.05 -0.07 -0.10 -0.10 -0.01  0.04  0.02  0.00  0.14 -0.09  0.09  0.06  0.14 -0.14 -0.09  0.08  0.16  0.05  0.01  0.09  0.05 -0.05  0.06 -0.06 -0.05
 [76,]  0.01  0.06 -0.08 -0.01 -0.14  0.04  0.06  0.00 -0.05  0.03  0.06  0.12  0.00 -0.06 -0.03  0.02 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.09 -0.11 -0.01  0.02 -0.10  0.03
 [77,]  0.07  0.00  0.01  0.04  0.01 -0.11 -0.01 -0.03 -0.09 -0.05 -0.04 -0.05  0.03 -0.05  0.02 -0.08  0.04  0.10 -0.02 -0.07 -0.01  0.08  0.02 -0.04 -0.14
 [78,] -0.08  0.00  0.02 -0.01 -0.03  0.02 -0.13 -0.09  0.00  0.08  0.05  0.06  0.04  0.10 -0.10 -0.01  0.04  0.02  0.04  0.11 -0.01  0.07 -0.04  0.02 -0.04
 [79,] -0.14 -0.01 -0.07 -0.14  0.04  0.01  0.01  0.08  0.08  0.08  0.01  0.10  0.01 -0.04 -0.01 -0.02  0.06  0.08  0.00  0.05 -0.03 -0.04  0.10  0.12 -0.01
 [80,]  0.07 -0.05  0.03  0.09  0.07  0.02  0.14  0.07 -0.04  0.10 -0.03 -0.05  0.04 -0.06  0.03 -0.11 -0.13  0.01  0.07 -0.10 -0.07  0.02 -0.03 -0.04 -0.05
 [81,]  0.07 -0.08 -0.02 -0.02  0.11 -0.06 -0.06 -0.05 -0.01  0.15  0.02 -0.02  0.00 -0.04 -0.04  0.03  0.09 -0.16 -0.03  0.00  0.14  0.12  0.03  0.02 -0.06
 [82,] -0.01  0.00 -0.02 -0.03  0.04  0.03  0.01 -0.06 -0.08  0.14  0.01  0.01  0.15  0.04  0.05  0.01  0.01 -0.08 -0.02 -0.05  0.06  0.11  0.13  0.19  0.08
 [83,] -0.05 -0.09  0.03 -0.06  0.06  0.05  0.12  0.07  0.00 -0.08  0.05  0.02  0.04 -0.03 -0.03 -0.03  0.02  0.00 -0.03  0.00 -0.13  0.02  0.13  0.05  0.07
 [84,]  0.00 -0.09  0.07  0.07  0.07 -0.07  0.11 -0.02 -0.02  0.06 -0.07  0.04 -0.04  0.05 -0.04  0.05  0.03 -0.10  0.09  0.01  0.02 -0.01 -0.05 -0.01  0.07
 [85,]  0.08  0.01  0.07  0.00 -0.07  0.03 -0.05  0.19  0.00  0.14 -0.04  0.08 -0.06  0.08  0.00 -0.03  0.01 -0.03  0.04  0.04 -0.05 -0.01  0.07  0.15  0.00
 [86,] -0.10 -0.02  0.01  0.11 -0.05  0.08 -0.08  0.04 -0.01 -0.06 -0.01  0.02  0.03 -0.04  0.04  0.02  0.08  0.05  0.05 -0.03  0.12 -0.05  0.04  0.05  0.18
 [87,]  0.07 -0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.11 -0.04  0.06 -0.07  0.08 -0.02  0.09 -0.10  0.07 -0.04  0.00  0.05  0.07  0.00  0.02  0.02  0.12  0.01  0.02  0.04  0.09
 [88,] -0.01  0.03  0.00 -0.10  0.09  0.02  0.00  0.02  0.04 -0.01  0.00 -0.11 -0.18 -0.08  0.09  0.07  0.07  0.09 -0.08  0.00  0.00 -0.03 -0.04  0.01  0.04
 [89,]  0.12  0.02  0.04  0.05  0.05  0.11  0.00 -0.03 -0.03  0.11  0.01  0.00 -0.05 -0.11 -0.01 -0.03 -0.04 -0.05 -0.09 -0.06 -0.05  0.02  0.07 -0.05 -0.06
 [90,] -0.05 -0.01 -0.08 -0.04  0.10  0.04  0.00 -0.12  0.14 -0.12 -0.03 -0.06 -0.01 -0.09  0.04  0.03 -0.07  0.05  0.06 -0.05  0.17 -0.12  0.09 -0.11  0.02
 [91,] -0.06  0.03 -0.12  0.03  0.01 -0.08 -0.02  0.02  0.01  0.08 -0.04  0.04  0.09  0.05  0.04 -0.06  0.00  0.01 -0.02  0.10  0.01  0.02 -0.02  0.02 -0.07
 [92,]  0.09  0.01  0.10  0.10  0.10 -0.10  0.01 -0.01 -0.10 -0.06 -0.04 -0.09 -0.06 -0.12  0.00  0.06 -0.01 -0.02  0.02  0.09 -0.08  0.01 -0.01 -0.13  0.05
 [93,]  0.05 -0.04 -0.05  0.11  0.00 -0.02 -0.16 -0.13 -0.01 -0.03  0.11  0.10  0.02 -0.07 -0.01  0.05  0.10 -0.01  0.07 -0.01 -0.01 -0.02  0.08 -0.01  0.00
 [94,] -0.07  0.00 -0.07 -0.11  0.05 -0.01 -0.03 -0.03 -0.06  0.09  0.02  0.00 -0.09  0.01  0.08  0.06 -0.01 -0.05 -0.15  0.17  0.02  0.11 -0.05  0.01  0.01
 [95,] -0.10 -0.08 -0.03 -0.15  0.00  0.03  0.03  0.06 -0.04  0.04 -0.10 -0.04  0.04  0.04  0.04  0.07  0.05  0.07  0.01  0.02 -0.13  0.00  0.06  0.05  0.02
 [96,]  0.13 -0.01 -0.08 -0.04 -0.03  0.00  0.03 -0.02  0.02 -0.07  0.00  0.01 -0.07 -0.11  0.11  0.03  0.02  0.05  0.10  0.13 -0.03 -0.01  0.13  0.01  0.00
 [97,] -0.02 -0.08 -0.12 -0.11 -0.08 -0.04 -0.10 -0.04 -0.04  0.03  0.00  0.20  0.03  0.04 -0.03  0.11 -0.08  0.09 -0.06  0.09  0.07 -0.04 -0.02 -0.01 -0.01
 [98,] -0.02  0.08  0.05  0.04 -0.11 -0.02 -0.01  0.01  0.03  0.01 -0.07 -0.07  0.03  0.01 -0.10 -0.05 -0.13  0.00  0.00 -0.04 -0.07  0.10  0.08  0.07 -0.11
 [99,]  0.04  0.04  0.06 -0.03  0.00  0.04  0.09  0.05 -0.03 -0.09  0.14 -0.03  0.09 -0.03 -0.04 -0.08  0.02 -0.10 -0.13  0.08  0.00 -0.11  0.03 -0.01 -0.07
[100,] -0.04 -0.18  0.08 -0.05 -0.07  0.02 -0.02  0.03  0.00  0.04  0.00  0.14 -0.12 -0.12  0.07 -0.06  0.06  0.02 -0.06 -0.07 -0.08  0.03 -0.03  0.02  0.00
```

Depending on what you are looking for, of course.

If you want to know where the correlations are that are larger than a particular value:

```
which(abs(x) > 0.2 & x < 1, arr.ind=TRUE)


> which(abs(x) > 0.2 & x < 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
      row col
 [1,]  14   1
 [2,]   9   8
 [3,]   8   9
 [4,]   1  14
 [5,]  99  33
 [6,]  62  35
 [7,]  48  45
 [8,]  45  48
 [9,]  89  49
[10,]  97  60
[11,]  35  62
[12,]  75  63
[13,]  84  74
[14,]  63  75
[15,]  80  76
[16,]  76  80
[17,]  74  84
[18,]  49  89
[19,]  60  97
[20,]  33  99
```

If you want to know the values of the correlations:

```
x[which(abs(x) > 0.2 & x < 1, arr.ind=TRUE)]

 [1] -0.23 -0.26 -0.26 -0.23 -0.22  0.25  0.21  0.21 -0.21 -0.22  0.25  0.21  0.22  0.21  0.21  0.21  0.22 -0.21 -0.22 -0.22
```